# Xenserver 5.5 doesn't see RAID volume

Tags: linux, raid, xen, dell, xenserver

I am trying to install Xenserver on a Dell precision 490 workstation. After booting into the install wizard and next-ed a few times, On the disk step, it only shows physical harddrive but not the RAID (RAID-10) volume that I set up on the Dell RAID.

Is there a special option that I have to set on the boot? or do I need a special driver for this?

Please Advise
Thanks

Comment: What's the RAID controller? If it's a workstation, it's probably a cheapie and not a real RAID card. This may explain why XenServer doesn't see it.

Comment: The RAID controller is onboard controller - Intel 5000x chipset and running Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager.

I am able to setup RAID 10 and run windows 7 no problem. But I want to repurpose it to a xenserver and run windows on top.

Answer (score 1):

Given that none of the [supported RAID controllers for the Precision 490](http://www.dell.com/us/en/corp/desktops/precn_490/pd.aspx?refid=precn_490&s=corp) support RAID-10, but apparently you've done something magical with the on-board controller (or Dell are, shockingly, wrong).

The "RAID" controller in the 5000 chipset isn't real hardware RAID, though, so it won't work under Linux.  Just use Linux software RAID instead.

Comment: setup screen shows the 4 SATA disks that I have installed. not the volume0 on the RAID manager. 

Not sure why the website only shows 0,1,5 but I am able to setup 10 and run windows 7. so I am pretty sure it works.